# While generating as signed APK I got this Error :app:minifyReleaseWithR8 FAILED

Tags: android, build.gradle, proguard, android-build

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in D:\AndroidStudioProjects\W-Android\app\build\outputs\mapping\release\missing_rules.txt.","sources":[{}]}

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Missing class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt (referenced from: okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform.buildIfSupported() and 2 other contexts)\r\nMissing class org.conscrypt.OpenSSLProvider (referenced from: java.security.Provider okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform.getProvider())","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}

Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in D:\AndroidStudioProjects\W-Android\app\build\outputs\mapping\release\missing_rules.txt.

Missing class org.conscrypt.Conscrypt (referenced from: okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform.buildIfSupported() and 2 other contexts)

Missing class org.conscrypt.OpenSSLProvider (referenced from: java.security.Provider okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform.getProvider())

I am trying to generate signed bundle / apk in Android studio, and could not generate the apk to launch in google play store. Help me to find the solution for this.

Comment: Enable ```proguard rules``` in the project

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the path to \app\build\outputs\mapping\release\missing_rules.txt. Then open missing_rules.txt file and will show you the rules to add to your proguard-rules pro files

Answer (score 0):

go to your proguard-rules.pro file and add the following lines

```
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.Android10Platform
```